# How to fix a pipe in C++

Tags: c++, unix, process, pipe, fork

I am still a novice when it comes to UNIX and C++, creating a sort of unruly mess.

My task is to create a pipe, fork the process, let the parent process read in characters from a text file, pass those characters through the pipe to the child process, have the child process convert the case of the character from uppercase to lowercase or vice versa, then output the character.

When I run this code I see the following error: `(null) Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)`

When I put sleeper print statements into the program, I saw that the program located the file, forked properly, but while the child process began, the parent wouldn't start.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    FILE* fh;
    fh = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    int pipeID[2];
    pipe(pipeID);
    int len;

    if (fork() == 0) //this is the filter process
    {
        char filter[len];
        read(pipeID[0], filter, len);
        if (filter[0] >= 'a' && filter[0] <= 'z')
            filter[0] = filter[0] - 32;
        else if (filter[0] >= 'A' && filter[0] <= 'Z')
            filter[0] = filter[0] + 32;
        printf("%s", filter[0]);
    }

    else {
        char ch;
        char* toFilter;
        for (ch = getc(fh); ch != EOF; ch = getc(fh)) {
            printf("%s", ch);
            write(pipeID[1], &ch, len);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `len` is uninitialised?

Comment: @AlanBirtles, yes, but even instantiated, I get a similar error, though there is no null

Comment: Have you used a debugger to find where the segfault occurs?

Comment: Have you checked that `fopen` succeeds?

Comment: @klutt I do not have a debugger installed as far as I am aware

Comment: @AlanBirtles The short answer is no, I haven't, but I placed a print statement both before and after ```fopen``` and they both printed fine

Comment: @AlanBirtles I just checked and the file did not throw a NULL, so yes, it is open

Comment: Isn't gdb installed?

Comment: @klutt Yes, I suppose it is!  I'll try giving that shot, though I haven't used debugging software in this environment yet.

Comment: Also, compile with `-Wall -Wextra` and fix your warnings.

Comment: @klutt It simply says that it receives the segmentation fault at the line where the ```else``` occurs

Comment: @klutt I'll be honest, I have absolutely no idea how to compile with that.  I'm working inside visual studio code and have a compile file already set up

Comment: @Alt Then you need to learn how to do that. Being able to analyze warnings are crucial to debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you printing characters and using string specifiers?
You are probably accessing some not allowed memory locations..
Try using %c instead of %s.

Answer (score 0):

I see one major problem with several other glitches. Based on your code, I modified like this (still not good), and please see comments prefacing `#<num>`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* fh;
    fh = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    int pipeID[2];
    pipe(pipeID);
    /* int len; */  // #1 `len` is not needed

    if (fork() == 0)
    {
        close(pipeID[1]); // #2-1 usually we close unused end of pipe
        char filter[1024];
        int read_len;
        while ((read_len = read(pipeID[0], filter, sizeof(filter))) > 0) // #3 see below
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < read_len; ++i)
            {
                if (filter[i] >= 'a' && filter[i] <= 'z')
                    filter[i] = filter[i] - 32;
                else if (filter[i] >= 'A' && filter[i] <= 'Z')
                    filter[i] = filter[i] + 32;

                printf("%c", filter[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        close(pipeID[0]); // #2-2 same as #2-1
        char ch;
        /* char* toFilter; */ // #4 remove unused variable
        while ((ch = getc(fh)) != EOF) { // #5 a while is better than for
            printf("%c", ch);   // #6 %s -> %c
            write(pipeID[1], &ch, sizeof(char)); // #7 len -> sizeof(char)
        }
    }
}
```

The biggest problem is in the #3 part. You may think once you write to a pipe, the other end of pipe will immediately read the data. However, you can't rely on exactly one char is written and then read. So you need read as much as possible alternately until an `EOF` indicating the end of writing. Therefore, I changed the code as #3.

As for other problems, they are not really faulty. I think these are caused by carelessness.

Comment: thank you very much.  This post makes a lot of sense and I finally understand what I was doing incorrectly.  Your edits are very helpful and I got the code working.  Thank you again